# UniqueConstraint working only in django admin site

Tags: python, mysql, django

Hello I'm facing some issues with the UniqueConstraint class on my model.
Here is my model :

```py
class ModeleEquipement(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fabricant = models.ForeignKey(FabricantEquipement, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default='')
    type = models.ForeignKey(TypeEquipement, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default='')
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['fabricant', 'type', 'reference', 'designation'], name='unique_model_constraint')
        ]
```

I have a form in my site to select Fabricant, Type and to fill reference and designation and then post it to add the object in the backend with this code :

```py
form = ModeleEquipementForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
   fabricant = FabricantEquipement.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data["fabricant"])
   type = TypeEquipement.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data["type"])
   ModeleEquipement.objects.create(
       designation=form.cleaned_data["designation"],
       reference=form.cleaned_data["reference"],
       fabricant=fabricant,
       type=type
       )
```

And the form looks like this :

```py
class ModeleEquipementForm(forms.Form):
    fabricant = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select())
    type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select())
    reference = forms.CharField(label="Référence", max_length=20)
    designation = forms.CharField(label="Désignation", max_length=50)
    action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'value': 'add_modele'}))
```

But unfortunately, I can add duplicate rows with this code. And it's also working when I add manually in the MySQL database. But the constraint is working when I use the Admin part of my site to try to add a new row manually. That's the only way I interpreted that my constraint is active in Django model but I don't understand how I can add duplicates with the create() method in my code then. Does anyone have a clue on how I can resolve this issue ?

Comment: Did you make migrations and migrate? What database version do you use, in some old versions MySQL "registered" the constraints, but did not enforce these.